# ModelAndView and ModelMap in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/testmap", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView testmap(ModelAndView model) {
        ModelMap map=new ModelMap();
        String greetings = "Greetings, Spring MVC! testinggg";
        model.setViewName("welcome");
        map.addAttribute("message", greetings); 
        return model;
    }
```

I had

```
${message}
```

on welcome.jsp. But it does not prints the greetings.
Can you tell me the reason?

Comment: Why do you think it should be _printed_? What exactly do you mean with "printed"?

Comment: Additionally, what exactly is your question? The title and the question differ!

Comment: Print where? Please provide more context, and why do you want to use both `Model` and `ModelAndView` together? You can set the model attributes in ModelAndView itself using `addObject(attributeName, attributeValue)` method.

Comment: I had edited the question. I just only need the reson for it.

Comment: Have you tried the way suggested in above comment?

Answer (score 1):

**Model** is an Interface. It defines a holder for model attributes and is primarily designed for adding attributes to the model. It contains four addAttribute (Overloaded) and one mergeAttributes  and one containsAttribute method.

Example:

```
 @GetMapping("/showViewPage")
public String passParametersWithModel(Model model) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("spring", "mvc");
    model.addAttribute("message", "Baeldung");
    model.mergeAttributes(map);
    return "viewPage";
}
```

**ModelAndView** is a class which allows us to pass all the information required by Spring MVC (Model and View) in one return.

Example :

```
@GetMapping("/goToViewPage")
public ModelAndView passParametersWithModelAndView() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("viewPage");
    modelAndView.addObject("message", "Baeldung");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Hope you get some clarity from this.